# You start with 19 cookies. 1 cookie is eaten away every day but you also earn 1/4 of a cookie every day... How many days will your cookies last?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You start with 19 cookies. 1 cookie is eaten every day but you also earn 1/4 of a cookie every day. When you have no cookies left, your score is how many days you lasted. How much score will you earn with 19 cookies? How do you calculate how many days you have left at any day only knowing your cookie count and bonus cookie count?

Python code:

```
cookie = 19
day = 0
result = 0

while True:
    cookie = cookie - 1
    cookieBonus = day / 4
    if (cookie + cookieBonus <= 0):
        result = day / 1
        break
    print("Cookie: " + repr(cookie))
    print("Bonus: " + repr(cookieBonus))
    print("Total: " + repr(cookie + cookieBonus))
    print((cookie + cookieBonus)*4/3.0) // Answer formula that calculates how many days you have left until no cookies, but how is this derived?
    day = day + 1

print()
print("Result: " + repr(result))
```

*Edit : The code doesn't match the logic of the question. I will re ask in another thread. I'll just let the problem slide in this question since we already have an answer of this particular question. As you can see in the code, the bonus cookie = day / 4 and you don't get to keep the bonus cookie the next day.

Comment: ....you lose 3 quarters of a cookie every day?

Comment: Why does cookie + cookieBonus*4/3.0 tell me how many days I have left ?

Comment: Actually I just understood now. The logic is not multiply by 4/3 it's divide by 3/4. I understand now.

Comment: Don't you need only to find the zeros of $19-x+\frac{1}{4}x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that a Python program is needed for this.

We are going to compute in units of quarter cookies. The rules are as follows: Four quarter cookies are eaten during the day, and one quarter cookie is put in the jar before going to bed.

*Claim:* When there are $m\geq1$ quarter cookies in the jar at 6 a.m. we shall survive $$\left\lfloor{m-1\over3}\right\rfloor$$
full days and starve on the following day.

This is easy to check when $1\leq m\leq 3$, and follows by induction for larger $m$. When there are $4\cdot19=76$ quarter cookies in the jar on the first morning we shall starve on day $26$.

Comment: Python was not needed, but it was where the problem came from. So why not show it. I had to rename all the variables to make this suitable for math stack exchance :D.